# Concatenating column values into row values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the below- both columns are strings, with the ValCol being a string of comma separated integers. The index is a generic integer index with no meaning.

```
NameCol    ValCol
Name1      555, 333
Name2      433
Name1      999
Name3      123
Name2      533
```

What's the best way to aggregate it to

```
NameCol    ValCol
Name1      555, 333, 999
Name2      433, 533
Name3      123
```

T don't care about the order of the comma separated integers, but I do need to keep commas between them. It likely will be a very small dataframe, <100 records, so efficiency isn't critical.

I feel like there should be some groupby approach to this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `groupby` approach:

```
df = df.groupby('NameCol')['ValCol'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
  NameCol         ValCol
0   Name1  555, 333, 999
1   Name2       433, 533
2   Name3            123
```

Comment: That makes so much sense and is very clean, thank you!